# how to give service name and port in configmap yaml?

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

I have a service (CusterIP) like following which is exposing ports of backend POD.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: fsimulator
  namespace: myns
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    application: oms
  ports:
    - name: s-port
      port: 9780
    - name: b-port
      port: 8780
```

Front end POD  should be able to connect to Backend POD using service. Should we replace hostname with service name to connect from Frontend POD to Backend POD ?

I have to supply the service name and port through environment variables to Frontend POD container.
The enviroment variables are set using configMap.

Is it enough to give service name fsimulator as hostname to connect to ?
How to give service if is created inside namespace ?

Thanks

Comment: Elaborate your question with what you are trying to do, to start-off with it would be helpful if you update with the deployment config and service config and what are you expecting to be passed where from configmap?

Comment: Please use Kubernetes service discovery instead of inventing something with config map

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#discovering-services). The internal service PORT / IP pairs for active services are indeed passed into the containers *by default*.

As the documentation also says, it is possible (recommended) to use a DNS cluster add-on for service discovery. Accessing `service.namespace` from outside / inside a service will resolve to the correct service route (or just `service` from inside the namespace). This is usually the right path to take.

Built-in service discovery is a huge perk of using Kubernetes, use the available tools if at all possible!